# Angular Image [src] error 431 Request Header Fields Too Large onload base 64

Tags: angular, request

i've this html
`<img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(d.image)" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Image" />`
but not show the image, and have the error in the ask.
I've tried if my base64 image is correct, and working perfectly in a simple html page.
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I realized I didn't have the Data URI scheme.
Try this instead

```
sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + d.image)
```

Answer (score 0):

If u have d.image as string and it contains also the Data URI scheme, try

`` this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`${JSON.parse(d.image)}`); ``